# Prove a set which conatins one point from each class in circle of circumference 1 is nonmeasureable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> (Kolmogrov,p268,problem 7) Let C be a circle of circumference 1 and let $\alpha\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. Let all points f C which can be obtained from each other by rotating C through an angle $n\alpha\pi$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$) be assigned to the same class (Clearly each such class contains countably many points). Let $\Phi_0$ be any set containing one point from each class. Prove that $\Phi_0$ is nonmeasureable. Hint: $$C=\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty\Phi_n$$and $$\Phi_m\cap\Phi_n=\emptyset\quad(m\neq n)$$ If $\Phi_0$ was measureable $\mu(\Phi_0)=\mu(\Phi_n)$ but $$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\mu(\Phi_n)=1$$.

Even though a hint was given I can't understand where the contradiction come from (or to plot in my mind how C and his classes looks like). In fact my main question is suppose we assumed that $\Phi_0$ is measureable then what would be its measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measure of $\Phi_0$ is either $0$ or some positive $a>0$. In the first case, the sum of all $0$'s gives $0$ for the left of your last equation (which is not the $1$ on the right side). In the second case, one has an infinite series of all terms the same positive constant $c$, which diverges to $+\infty$ and so again cannot match the $1$ on the right of the last equation.

Note this is a version on the circle of a standard construction of a nonmeasurable set using Hamel basis. (so that could be a start for  google searc). In that proof, two reals are regarded as equivalent if they differ by a rational, and one point from ech equivalence class is chosen to make the nonmesurable set.